Send email using C with the curl library, not working
I need to send an email using C, I'm trying to do this using the curl library. However, when trying to run the program it does nothing and simply returns this message in the console:
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
If you try to use debug mode it ignores all breakpoints and ends the program in the same way but now with code -1.
If you are not using curl, the program works normally.
This is my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#define FROM "email@gmail.com"
#define TO  "password"

static const char *headers_text[] = {
        "Date: Tue, 22 Aug 2017 14:08:43 +0100",
        "To: " TO,
        "From: " FROM " (Example User)",
        "Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@"
        "rfcpedant.example.org>",
        "Subject: example sending a MIME-formatted message",
        NULL
};

static const char inline_text[] =
        "This is the inline text message of the email.\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "  It could be a lot of lines that would be displayed in an email\r\n"
        "viewer that is not able to handle HTML.\r\n";

char * send_email(){

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
        struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;
        struct curl_slist *slist = NULL;
        curl_mime *mime;
        curl_mime *alt;
        curl_mimepart *part;
        const char **cpp;

        /* This is the URL for your mailserver */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, FROM);
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, TO);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT_ALLOWFAILS, 1L);
        for(cpp = headers_text; *cpp; cpp++)
            headers = curl_slist_append(headers, *cpp);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        mime = curl_mime_init(curl);
        alt = curl_mime_init(curl);

        part = curl_mime_addpart(alt);
        curl_mime_data(part, inline_text, CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_slist_free_all(recipients);
        curl_slist_free_all(headers);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_mime_free(mime);

    }
    return "ok";
}

And my CMakeList.txt is the following:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(aplicacao_back_end C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)


include_directories(lib\\libmicrohttpd\\include)
link_directories(lib\\libmicrohttpd\\lib)

set(CURL_LIBRARY "-lcurl")
include_directories(lib\\libcurl\\include)
link_directories(lib\\libcurl\\lib)
find_package(CURL)

add_executable(aplicacao_back_end main.c
        scripts/email.c
        scripts/email.h
)

target_link_libraries(aplicacao_back_end microhttpd ws2_32 curl)

I tried to track down the error, apparently the problem occurs after the line curl = curl_easy_init();.
I am using the CLion environment. And my folder structure is as follows:
.idea
cmake-build-debug
CMakeLists.txt
controller
lib

libcurl


include




lib


libmicrohttpd
sqlite3.c
sqlite3.h
sqlite3.lib
main.c
scripts
email.c
email.h


Since you use CURLOPT_VERBOSE there should come quite a lot of output to help with debugging.

you're not using READDATA properly: check the doc https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READDATA.html. You have to set a non-null CURLOPT_READFUNCTION callback instead that returns the number of bytes to read when curl calls it. With no such function, you have to pass a FILE * pointer to READDATA else it crashes.

I tried to put CURLOPT_VERBOSE, but it didn't show anything, it seems to stop executing even before the first line. As for CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, thanks for the tip, I tried implementing it, but as I said before it seems to simply ignore all lines. Despite this, I will update the code to comply with the documentation.

0xC0000135 is dll not found error. You likely link your program with the export libraries and later your app can't find dll files (libcurl.dll and/or sqlite3.dll)
